# Xcode - use var from different ViewControllers

Tags: objective-c

I got 2 ViewControllers. One for my configuration and one for the test app i am building. So what i want is to set a Textfield in my konfigViewController and to use this value i type into this textfield, in my mainViewController.

So how do I get a connection between these different ViewControllers? i already tried to include the konfigViewController.h in the mainViewController.m.

In konfigViewController.h the textfield is declared. The Viewcontroller is also linked to the .h &.m file.

Comment: This is not related to Xcode.

Comment: You should search on this site -- some variant of this question has been asked and answered thousands of times.

Comment: hmm i'm a bit worried about reading, that this is not related to Xcode? Im a beginner in xcode but this seems to be a basic feature to me. never the less i already searched for this, but I'm not finding a detailed description of what I'm searching for.